# For Groovy, can I embed a boolean value in a string?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

For example, is the string `"PRESERVE_CLUSTER=${!params.DELETE_CLUSTER_ON_ERROR} ./run-functional-tests.sh"` valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly valid.

You should watch for toString()-gotchas for locale-dependent or other complex data types.
Groovy doesn't do magic and uses each object's `toString()` method. In case of boolean there's nothing to worry about though.

Answer (score 1):

Just some completion regarding the treatment of booleans and strings. Non-empty strings are always evaluated to true so `!"true"` and `!"false"` are both evaluated to false. Instead, you may consider a safer version using toBoolean(), working fine for both booleans and string variables.

```
false_bool = false
false_str = "false"
assert "${!false_bool}" == "true"
//assert "${!false_str}" == "true"   // this will fail

// use toBoolean() is safer
assert "${!false_bool.toBoolean()}" == "true"
assert "${!false_str.toBoolean()}" == "true"
```